# Correct Wording: Esteem of/from your colleagues

Tags: word-choice, grammar

In regards to being shown admiration from others, how should the following be worded?

.. .esteem from your colleagues

or

... esteem of your colleagues

Answer (score 2):

*Esteem from your colleagues* is the correct way to put it.

The [Oxford entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/esteem):

> **esteem** (*noun*)
>   Respect and admiration, typically for a person

Since *esteem* is **for** someone, *esteem from your colleagues* is correct. For example, if you were to show love **for** someone, that person receives love **from** you.

Comment: Both forms can be appropriate; one could certainly be the recipient of the love of another.  Likewise the esteem of another.

Comment: @PaulGriffin It doesn't make sense to receive the love _of_ someone. In that context, you're saying you're receiving the love you have for someone.

Comment: No, you're saying you're receiving the love belonging to them.  Just like you could receive the backpack of another person.  It's theirs.  They gave it to you.

Comment: @PaulGriffin True. I think _from_ is much clearer though.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriateness of the form would depend on the structure of the sentence.  Both can be used:

> She desired esteem from her peers

Or

> She desired the esteem of her peers

Both express the same idea, and both would be correct usage, although as an American speaker, the second sounds more natural to my ear.